# Java catching Exception FileNotFound not working

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

I am trying to catch the FileNotFound exception so that my program will print a message when the exception is thrown, and not print the exception. Here is my code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class SeegeeSOGFinder10
{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException, IOException
    {
        // Some code here

        int i = 0;

        if(choice.equalsIgnoreCase("blah"))
        {
            try
            {
                while(i < j)
                {
                    // Loop code
                    i++;
                }
            }
            catch(java.net.SocketTimeoutException e) // This is where I am having trouble, These 2 exceptions are still thrown and are printed and my message is not shown
            {
                System.out.println("Recieved HTTP timeout. Maybe we got rate limited? Slepping for 30 seconds.");
                Thread.sleep(30000);
            }
            catch(java.io.FileNotFoundException e)
            {
                System.out.println("File Not Found!");
            }

            System.out.println("Done!");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Invalid Choice");
        }
    }

    // Some more code
}
```

The code is commented where I am having trouble, both of those errors are still thrown, and my message is not printed. I have tried enclosing the try catch block inside of the loop, and even putting the whole program in a try catch block, same results.

Comment: If you expect help for free here, you should at least format your code!

Comment: @MrSmith42 It kind of got messed up while I was removing unnecessary code. Sorry :/

Comment: Which message is not printed?

Comment: The code which you have shown doesn't contain any statements about working with file.

Comment: @Nambari "File Not Found!" and "Recieved HTTP timeout. Maybe we got rate limited? Slepping for 30 seconds." are not printing.

Comment: There's nothing involving files *in* this code.

Comment: @CJSculti why do you sure that your code must print those messages?

Comment: @BrianRoach There is, in the loop etc. I took that part of the code out as it is long and not necessary.

Comment: @Andremoniy It needs to print those messages so the user knows what went wrong...

Comment: @CJSculti If you care about printing something then you can use `finally` block

Comment: Show the result of the thrown exception. (the stuff that **does** get printed)

Comment: Try `System.err` because it is not buffered (The last outputs to `System.out` may get lost because of the buffering if `System.out`)

Comment: @smit Its not only printing stuff, its more that I dont want the user to see "java.io.FileNotFoundException" which they still do.

Comment: @CJSculti, if you want receive help, you have to show us those lines of code, in which you deal with a files.

Comment: If you are expecting an exception, show us THAT code, and maybe we can help.  Don't show us boilerplate code and expect us to tell you why it's doing exactly what it's written to do.

Comment: exception must be throwing outside the try....maybe in the block 

// Some code here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

catch will only catch exceptions throw inside its try block. The most likely cause of the method as a whole throwing the exception but it not being caught is that it is thrown from somewhere else, possibly something this method calls outside the try-catch block.

I suggest putting the block around all the code in the method. That way, you should catch the exception and be able to display the stack trace, including the line number in that causes the exception.

Comment: Another possibility is that the exception is thrown from inside a method called in the try block, but that the method catches the exception and prints its stack trace. That's what nearly every newbie does when the compiler tells them that an exception must be caught or declared.

Comment: @JBNizet Indeed. The real vice is continuing in an invalid state with neither an exception nor an exit. Again, actually looking at the stack trace will help.

Comment: This was it. The loop was calling another method, it was in that method that the exception was being thrown. Thanks guys!